# Neural net patience moving average

Tags: neural-network, validation

To my understanding, when we use patience = 8 when training a neural net, if there is no improvement on the loss (usually the validation set loss) for 8 epochs, then we would stop the training and take the model from 8 epochs ago as our "trained model".

An issue I see with this is that maybe the model trained 8 epochs ago was just lucky and happened to perform well on the validation set.

A way I could see around this would be to use a moving average of the loss (eg a moving average of 3 epochs). So every epoch we would calculate the average loss (using the loss from this epoch and the loss from the previous 2 epochs). Then with a patience = 8, we would stop training when the **average** loss doesnt improve for 8 epochs.

To choose a model from the 3 models that make up the best moving average, we could just take the one that actually scored lowest.

I believe this would mean we avoid fluke drops in the loss and so avoid models that "got lucky".

Do you think this would help much/at all or is this a waste of resources?

Comment: Good question. I think you've already answered everything, but to be more clear, yes, moving average is a better indicator of the stability of learning curves. (For anyone who's wondering how to this practically, you can write a custom callback.)